# UNIX System commands for iPhone to control services

Tags: iphone, command, jailbreak

I am looking for SpringBoard commands to control jailbroken iPhone programmatically, but theres hardly any information out there, or its pretty well hidden!  I would like to be able to talk to the ComCenter programmatically. Now I know this is not approved by Apple, but I dont care, I dont follow rules  ;-)

Anyone know of a good reference source for jailbroken commands for SpringBoard or ComCenter on 3.1.2 iPhone?

This is an example of what I am looking for:

```
NSString *cmd = (@"killall SpringBoard");
ssystem([cmd UTF8String]);
```

*Which restarts SpringBoard*

Comment: That looks like it's just running the unix command killall to shut down instances of the springboard. It's not talking to the springboard directly at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system("process unload /com.service.name");